# How to use extended JS syntax available in new browsers

Tags: javascript, syntax, bigint

I want to write a JavaScript function which uses new syntax (bigint literal `42n`) when browser supports it:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
     if (window.BigInt)
        FortyTwo = Function('return 42n;');
     else
        FortyTwo = function () {return 42;};
  </script>
```

But the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions) says:

> Note: Using the Function constructor to create functions is not recommended since it needs the function body as a string which may prevent some JS engine optimizations and can also cause other problems.

My function is CPU-intensive, so I don't want performance loss due to lack of "some JS engine optimizations".
I need some workaround.
I can split the script in two (the first one will fail on old browsers), but I doubt this is the best way:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
     FortyTwo = function () {return 42n;};
  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
     if (!window.FortyTwo) FortyTwo = function () {return 42;};
  </script>
```

What is the preferred way to include a script which uses new JS syntax?

Comment: Sometimes you have to make tradeoffs. If you need to use the `Function` constructor to get around this problem, you'll have to live without the optimizations.

Comment: If performance is an issue, you could make the function constructor, return a function, and then you use this..  This avoid's the performance issue.   Well it appears to work for Chrome anyway..

Comment: Actually, giving the V8 engine enough time, there is hardly any performance difference, if any.  I assume the TurboFan will kick in at some point anyway.  So in a nutshell I would say, don't worry about it.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert all your code automatically using [webpack](https://webpack.js.org/), [babel](https://babeljs.io/) and [cross-browser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cross-browser). There is some setup overhead but you can write all your code like this:

```js
alert(42n + 22n) // 64
```

You get most of the new syntax available with this approach, and even syntax that's not yet ready for release.

---

The other option - use a polyfill

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/big-integer/1.6.48/BigInteger.js"></script>
```

then write all your code like this

```js
alert(BigInt(42) + BigInt(2)) // 44
```

Comment: This is not really what the OP is after.

Comment: @Keith then what is he after?

Comment: Read the question,  in a nutshell.. He has a function that is CPU intensive, and he knows how to handle different browsers.  Using webpack & a bigInt polyfill is certainly not going to help with performance.  And in fact is likely to make things worse :(

Comment: @Keith Do you think a more generalized approach is useful? I mean it's pretty obvious there will be no engine optimizations to apply for `return 42n`. Besides, if that's all the code, it will run only once so ignore whatever overhead as well as the recommendation to avoid `eval()`.

Comment: Reading the OP's question, the `return 42n` is just a simple example.  Because he also says -> `My function is CPU-intensive`.   I agree with a more generalized approach, I use babel for transpiling, but do custom compiles for detected browsers.  Biggest drawback of webpack is how it degrades to the worst browser you support.